# Tic Tac Toe, playing with PC (random)

Tags: c, forms, tic-tac-toe

```
if (turn == tick) {
        /*first player*/
        Form1->Label1->Caption = "X pyr";
        fields[row][kol] = 1;
        Form1->BitBtn1->Glyph->LoadFromFile("tick.bmp");
        turn = tack;
    }

    else {
        do {
            //random
            row = rand() % 3;
            kol = rand() % 3;
        }
        while (fields[row][kol] == 0);

        /*cpu*/
        Form1->Label1->Caption = "CPU";
        fields[row][kol] = 2;
        Form1->BitBtn1->Glyph->LoadFromFile("tack.bmp");
        turn = tick;
    }

}
```

The main problem is that when I make my move, computer just clicks on first element and after every next move it does the same. 
Computer just uses first TicTacToe game board square.

Comment: Can you make your question clear? I think there is a problem with the variables `rinda` and `kolona`

Comment: Ok, did a little edit. Check first post.

Comment: What about making the question clear? As far as I understand computer makes its move to first column of first row, right?

Comment: Yes, you're right. And every next move it doe the same.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly the `fields` variable contain the board with 0 for unoccupied cell, 1 for human player, 2 for CPU.

In this case the terminal condition of the while is wrong `while (fields[row][kol] == 0);`, you must loop when the cell is occupied (trying to search for free cells).

```
do {
    //random
    row = rand() % 3;
    kol = rand() % 3;
}
while (fields[row][kol] != 0);
```

Note: you are initializing all elements of fields to 0, that don't appear in the code.

Comment: Now changes happens only in first square. When I click somewhere, changes happens only on the first square.

Answer (score 0):

CPU player loops until it finds a `row` and `col` value which is not equal to 0. `do-while` loop below loops if `fields[row][col]` is equal to 0 meaning after the exit `fields[row][col]` will be different than 0.

```
do {
    ...
} while(fields[row][col] == 0)

// fields[row][col] is different than 0 here
```

In your case field value not equal to 0 means a square already used by human or computer, so computer does the same move every time.